# How can I set the maximum number of rows in a page for longtable?

Tags: longtable

Making a complicated table is a pain in Latex.
I am using a `longtable` in my `tex` and need to change the maximum number of rows in a page.
Is there any way to set the maximum number of rows in a page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question

Comment: is your table going to span multiple pages?  is your intention to place other text/floats on the same page as your longtable or will only the longtable be on the page(s) (exempli gratia, an appendix for nomenclature)

Answer (score 4):

`longtable` does not count rows (and in any case the rows may be different heights because of vertical material such as p-columns). It uses an *output routine* to break the pages to a target height (`\textheight`) It is possible, with care, to change `\textheight` locally for a region of a document which is, I suspect, what you need here.